# Excel file, want to keep ID cell when filtering columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

[image]

I would like to filter column D , But need to keep the id from Column C to show. The easy way would to just have the column C list the code for each row, but that gets confusing when trying to get a count of the codes. Please help :)

Comment: If I understand you and what I see in the example, you want to filter column D and have the proc_code in C display for whatever value you've filtered in D; is this correct?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: @DavidCastanon,, what I've realized that, while Filter any Row or Value from `Column D` for example `Max=` you want to keep the Code in Column C `A4563` visible,, am I write? I guess values in `Col D`are in separate Rows,, has common Code !!

Comment: Now tell me are you also thinking to Filter more than one value from `Col D` like `Max=` & `UVSP=` with their respective Codes in `Col C`?

Comment: I have encountered this in some of my spreadsheets before, which are, granted rather small, but the only solution I know is to fill down each unique value. You could probably write a small macro to fill down until it encounters a new value, then start using the new value.

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve the issue by using Helper Column:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Insert blank column between **Code & Country Name** *(is Helper Column).*
- In Cell `B5` write this Formula `=A5`.
- Write this formula in Cell `B6` & fill down.

  ```
  =IF(A6="",B5,A6)
  ```
- Write **Country Name** to filter data in Cell `D2 & D3`.
- In Cell `E2` enter this Array formula, finish with `ctrl+Shift+Enter` then fill Right and Down.

  ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$5:$C$18, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2, $C$5:$C$18)+COUNTIF($D$3, $C$5:$C$18), ROW($A$5:$C$18)-MIN(ROW($A$5:$C$18))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- In your Sheet, insert a **Helper Column** between `Col C and D`.
- Purposely I've used 2 Country name as Criteria to justify the efficiency of the used Array Formula. This Formula will work with one Criteria also.
- If you use one Criteria then use this one.

  ```
     {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$5:$C$18, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2, $C$5:$C$18), ROW($A$5:$C$18)-MIN(ROW($A$5:$C$18))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.